# Some apps are not visible on play store of genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I have downloaded genymotion and virtual device Android API is `8.1 API 27` I have also installed open GAPPS.

When I use `playstore` and seach for `netflix` the app is not listed in the `playstore` (When I search it through chrome I get messgae `Your device isn't compatible with this version` ). Is there some problem with my Android API config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon prime video is ARM only, while Genymotion VD architecture is x86. You need to install ARM translation tools to interpret ARM into x86. See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002676057-I-cannot-install-or-run-an-application-in-Genymotion-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

DuoS? Haven't tried Netflix but Amazon Prime Video did work for me, so worth a shot?

Comment: Amazon prime video also show the same message `Your device isn't compatible with this version`.

Comment: Install the DuoS emulator and you can try in there.